# How to programatically move a horizontal scroll view half way in android?

Tags: java, android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

In my android app, I build a horizontal scroll view and add contents and add it to the DOM. How can I (using java) move the scroll bar to the half way point of it?

Thanks.

This code doesn't work

```
        Context context = carousel_container.getContext();

        HorizontalScrollView hsv = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
        LinearLayout carousel = new LinearLayout(context);
        setGallery(carousel);

        addFishes();

        hsv.addView(carousel, new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        carousel_container.addView(hsv, new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        hsv.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int offsetX = hsv.getWidth()/2;
                //int offsetX = hsv.getMaxScrollAmount()/2;
                hsv.scrollTo(offsetX, 0);
             }
        }, 10000);
```

Comment: What type of layout is the scroll view in?

Comment: I add the horizontal scrollview in a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: Did you try hsv.scrollTo(hsv.getMaxScrollAmount()/2, 0);  ?

Comment: You should probably add an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to listen for when the `HorizontalScrollView` is laid out. After that you can call `getWidth()` and do `hsv.scrollTo(hsv.getWidth()/2);`, but not before, since the `getWidth()` will return 0 before the view is laid out.

Comment: I am adding many horizontal layouts dynamically, not all at same time, but its based on when the user clicks a button. Does ongloballayoutlistener run everytime I add a horizontalview?

Comment: Can you use a relative layout instead?

Comment: Is a relative layout required for it to work?

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out by DeeV:

1. The layout has to be drawn first. Only then the views' widths will be greater than 0.
2. You can't use the HorizontalScrollViews width to scroll to the center. Use the inner view's width (in your case: carousel).

If your HorizontalScrollView is inside an Activity, use this to make sure the view is ready to be scrolled:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    // do scrolling here
}
```

If your HorizontalScrollView is inside a Fragment, either implement a callback to pass the "views-are-ready"-event to the Fragment, or use this code, which loops until that happens:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (hsv.getWidth() > 0) {
                // do scrolling here
            } else {
                mainThreadHandler.post(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now to the scrolling itself. hsv.scrollTo(carousel.getWidth()/2, 0) is suggested by others, but that won't do what you want it to. The first parameter of scrollTo(...) is the x-coordinate of the currently visible left edge of the inner view (i.e. a HorizontalScrollView x-scroll ranges from 0 to it's inner view's width minus the HorizontalScrollView's width). This means using carousel.getWidth()/2 will scroll the left edge of the screen to the center of your view. So, if you want to scroll to the center of your view, you should use this instead:

```
hsv.scrollTo((carousel.getWidth() - hsv.getWidth()) / 2, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue you're having is that your Views aren't inflated and don't have any sizes yet so your "scrollTo" is always going to be 0.  First, you need to wait until the ScrollView and it's contents are inflated.  The next thing is you can't use the ScrollView's width because it's the size of the screen.  You need to use the child's with (carousel) which is unbound (alternatively you may be able to use `getMaxScrollAmount()`).

The easiest thing to do is post a Runnable to it like so:

```
private class ScrollToCenter implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      hsv.scrollTo(carousel.getWidth()/2, 0);
   }
}

hsv.post(new ScrollToCenter());
```

Posting to a View will wait until the View is visible before doing executing.  If the View is already visible, then it will execute **almost** immediately.

Comment: can I pass parameters to `run()` for the hsv and carousel views?

Comment: You would need to use a Constructor for `ScrollToCenter` to pass in parameters or use getters/setters.

Comment: I updated my post above with your code, but it still did not work.

Comment: I even tried `hsv.scrollTo(hsv.getChildAt(0).getWidth()/2, 0);` and it didn't work.

Comment: Ok.  I just implemented the solution to one of my projects and it does work, but you have to wait till the carousel has filled out. Your carousel may not be completely done so its size is always 0. You can test this theory by swapping `post` with `postDelayed()` and setting the delay to 5000 milliseconds. Also, I used `getMaxScrollAmount()` and this only scrolled it the width of the `ScrollView`; not it's contents.

Comment: I tried with postdelayed with 10000 seconds, and `getMaxScrollAmount()` and nothing happened...

Comment: Then sorry this didn't help. There's something unique here that's out of the scope of the original question. Can you try hardcoding a scroll value instead?

Comment: I tried putting 500 as a hardcoded value, but still no effect.